# how to resolve Error C2440 'initializing': cannot convert from '_Ty' to '_Objty'

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying to write an algorithm for finding a subset of a given vector that has a certain requested sum.
I am trying to use the 'meet in the middle' technique as described in 'the competitive programmer's handbook' by Antti Laaksonen. here is my code:

```cpp
vector<int> subset_with_sum1(vector<int> set, int requested_sum) {
    int half = set.size() / 2;
    vector<int> set_a(set.begin(), set.begin() + half),
        set_b(set.begin() + half, set.end());
    auto subsets_a = get_subsets1(set_a),
        subsets_b = get_subsets1(set_b);
    vector<int> sums_a(subsets_a.size()), sums_b(subsets_b.size());
    transform(
        subsets_a.begin(),
        subsets_a.end(),
        sums_a.begin(),
        sum_vector
    );
    transform(
        subsets_b.begin(),
        subsets_b.end(),
        sums_b.begin(),
        sum_vector
    );
    for (int i = 0; i < sums_a.size(); i++)
        if (sums_a[i] == requested_sum)
            return subsets_a[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < sums_b.size(); i++)
        if (sums_b[i] == requested_sum)
            return subsets_b[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < sums_a.size(); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < sums_b.size(); j++)
            if ((sums_a[i] + sums_b[j]) == requested_sum) {
                vector<int> temp(subsets_a.begin(), subsets_a.end());
                temp.insert(temp.end(),subsets_b.begin(), subsets_b.end());
                return temp;
            }
}
```

this code produces the error mentioned in the title. here is the full error:

```
Error   C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from '_Ty' to '_Objty'   PracticeIOI C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\xmemory 671
```

this error appears in other questions on this website but always in relation to some user-defined classes and pointers, neither of which I use. the same goes for the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2440?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(C2440)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=vs-2019).
also, as the error occurs in an STL file, I can't even know which specific line of my code causes it.
how can I fix this?

EDIT: I didn't include some code that is necessary for running the function so here it is:

```cpp
vector<vector<int>> get_subsets1(vector<int> nums) {
    int full = 1 << nums.size();
    bitset<8 * sizeof(int)> set;
    vector<vector<int>> subsets;
    vector<int> temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < full; i++) {
        set = bitset<8 * sizeof(int)>(i);
        temp = vector<int>();
        for (int j = 0; j < nums.size(); j++)
            if (set[j])
                temp.push_back(nums[j]);
        subsets.push_back(temp);
    }
    return subsets;
}
int sum_vector(vector<int> vec) {
    return accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is on these lines:

```
vector<int> temp(subsets_a.begin(), subsets_a.end());
temp.insert(temp.end(),subsets_b.begin(), subsets_b.end());
```

Here `temp` is of type `vector<int>`, but `subsets_a` and `subsets_b` are of type `vector<vector<int>>`. Since the value types are `int` and `vector<int>` respectively, they don't match, and so this doesn't compile.

Depending on what you need, either make `temp` a `vector<vector<int>>`, or copy the individual `int`s in each `vector` of `subsets_a` and `subsets_b` into `temp`.

Comment: thank you. do you know a way for me to know when a type misalignment like this occurs and where? because all Visual Studio shows me is where the error occurs inside STL and not which line of my code causes it.

Comment: *One* way is to replace `auto` with the actual types you think they are, then the compiler will give you an error right at the problem code. However, it's better if you learn to read the error messages (that's how I spotted the problem). I'm sure there are ways that VS can be used to give you better quality error messages.